# Pause/Resume Youtube video when out of view (scrolled)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I'm using a javascript plugin that enables to play a background full-width youtube video:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".player").mb_YTPlayer();

    });
</script>

<script>
            var vids = ["list of videos"
            ]; // create your list of youtube videos

    var currVid = vids[Math.floor(Math.random()*(vids.length-1))]; // this will grab a random video from the array.

    var opts = { // keep all the options in an object
      videoURL: currVid, // set the video to display
      containment:'.video-section',
      quality:'large', 
      autoPlay:true, 
      mute:true, 
      opacity:1
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      document.getElementById("bgndVideo").dataset.property = JSON.stringify(opts); // change to this

      $(".player").mb_YTPlayer(); // play!
    });
</script>
```

How can I make it to pause when I scroll down on the website and resume when in viewport?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where is your attempt to monitor the scroll position to set the play state?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a `scroll` event listener to the container (probably the `window` object in your case, and then on every scroll try to calculate whether the video is in the visible viewport or not. Here's some helpful code:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var viewportTop = window.scrollY;
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.outerHeight;
    var isVideoBelowViewport = $(".player").offset().top > viewportBottom;
    var isVideoAboveViewport = $(".player").offset().bottom < viewportTop;
    var isVideoOutsideViewport = isVideoBelowViewport || isVideoAboveViewport;
    if ( isVideoOutsideViewport && isVideoPlaying() ) pauseVideo();
    if ( !isVideoOutsideViewport && !isVideoPlaying() ) resumeVideo();
});
```

I'll leave it up to you to write `isVideoPlaying()`, `resumeVideo()` and `pauseVideo()`.

Comment: $(".player").offset().bottom was not working for me. I changed it to $(".player").offset().top + $(".player").outerHeight(true).